# Selenium setup for Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver

When I tried to setup the selenium for a Visual Studio , I realized that there are no three main jar files in the lib that are Client-combined-....jar , okhttp-...jar and okio....jar. Then How can I add them?

I want to know how to add them for reffenced Libraries

Comment: Why do you need these jars ? Have you downloaded Selenium WebDriver package ?

Comment: JARs are for Java... what programming language are you using? Also, you should add the programming language as a tag to your question.

Comment: @Akzy I downloaded Selenium WebDriver package. I needed jars for add Referenced Libraries.As well as I am using JAVA as a language